# Python typing a Callable with *args while enforcing the first argument

Tags: python, class, type-inference, python-typing, callable

In the following code (working on PyCharm), I get an unexpected argument markup at the arguments following `self` inside the callable function.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import *

class G: 
    def __init__(self,callback: Callable[[G, ...], None]):
        self.callback_ = callback
    
    def f(self):
        self.callback_(self,1,2,3)
```

I have tried many things, but still to no avail. What can I do to avoid typing errors in code above?

my objective is that the callback functions first argument will be of type G and the rest of the arguments will be anything inputted elsewhere (something like *args)

Comment: Please correct your indentation first - currently this code is invalid.

Comment: Do you expect `self._callback` to take exactly argument of type `G`, followed by three integers? Otherwise the call like this is obviously unsafe, at least from static typing POV. You may want to use `Concatenate[G, _P]`, where `_P` is some `ParamSpec`, as `Callable` argument type, and make `G` generic in `_P`. You may type explicitly `Callable[[G, int, int, int], None]`. Please clarify your intent - I do not understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Does something like this work for you? https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=c030b4c1832ebd0167ce29b455cf847a

Answer (score 3):

The ellipsis (`...`) cannot be used in the context of `typing.Callable[[G, ...], None]` to express that one cares only about the first argument.

Use `typing.Protocol` instead:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Any, Protocol


class CallbackOnG(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, g: G, *args: Any, **kwds: Any) -> None:
        ...


class G:
    def __init__(self, callback: CallbackOnG):
        self.callback_ = callback

    def f(self):
        self.callback_(self, 1, 2, 3)
```